# Cognitive Sciences (cogsci.SE) would like to offer its services

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I am an active user on Cognitive Sciences, and in the midst of establishing a tag on [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting), stumbled upon the section of your FAQ advertising "sister sites" on the exchange.

We would like to offer our site as a resource for asking child psychology and developmental psychology questions that might be on your users' minds, but are too theoretical to be on-topic for Parenting.  The only minor limitation is that we discourage "self-help" questions, as those would be best answered by a professional.

Our [developmental-psychology](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/developmental-psychology) tag is fairly active, with 24 questions, including:

- [What is the effect of motherese on development?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/994/what-is-the-effect-of-motherese-on-development)
- [Do fetuses exhibit pattern recognition *in utero*?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/871/do-fetuses-exhibit-pattern-recognition-in-utero)
- [To what extent are correlations of father's age with birth defects and autism causal?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/635/to-what-extent-are-correlations-of-fathers-age-with-birth-defects-and-autism-ca)
- and more!

Our [parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenting) tag is just getting started, but includes:

- [Do men and women differ in their desire to have children?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/636/do-men-and-women-differ-in-their-desire-to-have-children)
- [Do victims of bad parenting become bad parents?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/639/do-victims-of-bad-parenting-become-bad-parents)
- and more!

We have an existing [question](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372/should-we-volunteer-as-a-sister-site-for-parenting) on our Meta about getting involved, so you are certainly welcome to leave your comments or concerns on this question or that one.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated our [faq](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/faq) to reflect the wording suggested in the [accepted answer](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/373/864) on the cogsci.se meta question.

If either the Cogsci.se or Parenting.se communities feel the wording should be tweaked further, we can certainly discuss and edit as needed.

Comment: Excellent!  We had made a note on our parenting tag that refers to your site, so hopefully everyone seeking information can find what they need.