# Cognitive Science Stack Exchange has been changing its name

Tags: discussion, status-completed

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Some subjects might be on-topic here but you can get better response on our sister sites, for instance:
>
> - Scientific questions about child psychology (see the developmental-psychology tag on Cognitive Sciences SE)

The site name has been changing to Psychology & Neurosciences SE since 2017. Should we reflect this change too?

<sup>Related:

• [Cognitive Science Reboot 2017: Changing the Name](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2301/12937)

• [Cognitive Sciences (cogsci.SE) would like to offer its services](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/357/13467)</sup>

Comment: Nice point - edited!